# Hacer convivir Quart y Asyncio

Tags: python, asyncio

No logro entender como hacer para que corra una app en quart, y conviva con otro proceso, quiero que independientemente de la renderizacion web que hace quart por detras corran otras funciones. Les dejo un codigo base con el cual estoy probando.

```
import asyncio

from quart import Quart

resultado=0


async def abar(a):
    print(a)

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route("/") async def notify():
    await abar("abar")
    return "OK"

async def suma():
    global resultado
    resultado=resultado+1
    print('sumando')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def controlador():
    print('corriendo controlador')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80,debug=True)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() cors = asyncio.wait([suma(),controlador()]) loop.run_until_complete(cors)
```

Comment: Hola, `app.run` genera su propio ciclo de eventos y bloquea la ejecución en esa línea, lo que hagas después simplemente no se ejecuta. ¿Las funciones que correrían "detrás" las llamarías como haces con `abar` o correrían desde que se ejecuta la app?¿Correrían hasta que la app esté en ejecución?¿cederían regularmente el control al event-loop o tienen tiempos largos de bloqueo?